# Invalid syntax error in google python api

Tags: python-2.7, google-api-python-client, google-app-engine-python

I am new to google python api client.I am learning from https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/start/get_started.I want to make an api which converts python object into JSON data and sends to a servlet.

The python code of file api.py:

```
import os
import urllib2
import httplib2
import json
import requests
from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.client import flow_from_clientsecrets
from oauth2client.tools import run_flow
from oauth2client.file import Storage
from oauth2client import tools

api_version='1'
_file_="D:\API"


CLIENT_SECRETS = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(_file_))

flow=flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRETS,
  scope=[
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.full_control',
      ],


http = httplib2.Http()
auth_http = credentials.authorize(http)

service=build('SendNotif',api_version,http=http)

req = urllib2.Request('http://example/notify')
req.add_header('Content-Type', 'application/json')

data={"message":"Hello User you are notified"}
data_json = json.dumps(data)

response = urllib2.urlopen(req, json.dumps(data))
```

The error shown is:

```
    D:\API>python api.py
    File "api.py", line 25
    auth_http = credentials.authorize(http)
        ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

please do help in correcting me..
 thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a closing parenthesis for this line:

```
flow=flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRETS,
```

Comment: Now it displays...                                                                                      ` ile "D:\API\try.py", line 76, in <module>
    main(sys.argv)
  File "D:\API\try.py", line 62, in main
    service = build(api_name,api_version,http=http)
  File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\util.py", line 135, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File  "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\discovery.py", line 202, in build
    version))
UnknownApiNameOrVersion: name: send  version: v1`

Comment: Read https://developers.google.com.com/api-client-library/python/apis/ the api version should be either v1 or v2, not 1. For future reference, if you have another question post it as a new question 